# Should I retain the argument with GCD dispatch_X (or does it retain it)

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, ios6, selector, grand-central-dispatch

As far as I remember we had something like `performSelectorOnMainThread:` (and variants) do retain the objects until the method is finished executing" in Apple's documentation. So can we rely on such behavior in ios6? Cause there isn't any info in the [NSObject Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) now. The same question in case I prefer using GCD `dispatch_async`/`sync` - if I have object created in back thread - should I choose `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue)` to be sure that object won't be released until selector executes.

Answer (score 0):

The thing about the Cocoa memory management system is that you NEVER have to care about this. Memory management is completely local -- you never care about what other functions do. The basic rule is -- **the caller guarantees that an object argument is valid when the function is called, and does not guarantee anything else**.

If a function somehow stores an object for use later, it MUST (by deduction) retain it somehow, since it does not assume that the object is valid for any longer. Conversely, as a caller of the function, you don't need to think about what a function does or whether it does something asynchronously or not, because you are not guaranteeing to the function that its argument is alive at any point after it's called.

Answer (score 0):

blocks, which GCD dispatch **capture** their context: In this case this means they retain everything they reference until executed :)